# How do I autolink a nearby file in CommonMark?

Tags: hyperlink, commonmark

I am creating a README.md file and in it I want to link to COPYING.md in the same directory. I tried the following markup, but the link is not rendered:

```
See <COPYING.md> for details.
```

How can I create such a link? (Obviously it depends on the renderer and context as to how the link is interpreted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An autolink requires an absolute URI, so that won't work. The following code is a bit more verbose, but achieves the desired output:

```
See [COPYING.md](COPYING.md) for details.
```

*References:*

- https://talk.commonmark.org/t/2460
- http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#uri-autolink